# How to read "Côte d'Ivoire" from JSON file python

Tags: python, json

I have to match data from a CSV and a JSON file.
Everything works except for when reading "Côte d'Ivoire" from the files. I have to match data based on country names.

When reading from CSV with the following code :

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(filename)
```

I get "Côte d'Ivoire"

```
"CIV","Côte d'Ivoire",1 ----line in csv file
```

But when reading from the JSON file with the following code :

```
json_data = json.loads(open(filename).read())
```

I get "CÃ´te d'Ivoire"

```
{
    "label": "CIV",
    "display": "Côte d'Ivoire",
    "display_sequence": 1
} ---- block in json file
```

So now when i compare the strings they done match and i love one countries data. I have opened both csv and json file with notepad++ to see both contain "Côte d'Ivoire".

I understand that this could be an encoding issue so i wanted to know how to read the JSON file so that this string is read correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the kind of garbling, I see that you are reading an UTF-8 file, while the default encoding on your system is Latin1 or windows-1252 (most probably the latter, since most UNIX systems from several years default to UTF-8, and on Windows windows-1252 is way more popular than the very similar Latin1).

Now, what is happening is that, by default, when you open a file in text mode Python 3 "helpfully" tries to decode it with the local encoding, whatever that happens to be.

What we want here, instead, is to read the raw bytes and decode them using the correct encoding. So, we have to open the file in binary mode, take the `byte` object that `read` now returns and `decode` it with the correct encoding so to get a `str` that we can use.

```
json_data = json.loads(open(filename, "rb").read().decode('utf-8'))
```

---

So, this was mostly to understand the steps involved for going from bytes to unicode strings; Python 3 luckily provides a simpler way: in text mode you can specify an encoding to use instead of the default one. So, we can go back to a simpler

```
json_data = json.loads(open(filename, encoding='utf-8').read())
```

which is also more efficient than the snippet above, given that the conversion is performed while reading, instead of having to convert the whole big string.

The tricky bit to keep in mind here is that `read` returns a `byte` object when you open the file in binary mode (so that you have to `decode` it manually to a `str` if you want to interpret it as textual data), or an already-decoded `str` object when you open it in text mode. In this last case, either your file is in whatever python thinks the default encoding is, or you have to explicitly specify the correct encoding, otherwise you'll read garbage.

Comment: Thank you, it's not so frequent to see an accepted answer trying to step down :-)

Comment: Mm if Latin1 is the default encoding most probably OP is on Windows.

Comment: Yes, but again, you are applying a global solution to a local problem. The encoding for files unfortunately is a case-by-case affair. IMO there should be no default for that. Either you are sure about the encoding for that particular file (and you actually *need* to convert the stuff to unicode strings), or you just open the file in binary mode and just read *bytes*.

Comment: The solution is wrong because you are stomping over all the locale settings, not just the default encoding. Again, IMO it's a bad idea but at least execute it correctly.